# How to add a field in Firestore collection using Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

I want to add a field in the DB collection after the user has created that is a boolean, like isAdmin: false. Creation of user and adding doc to the DB is working but I'm not sure if I should add it while adding the doc or use updateDoc. I tried this but not working:

```
await updateDoc(collection(firestore, "Users", User.id), {
  isAdmin: false
});
```

I'm using Next.js and react-firebase-hooks. Thanks in advance for any help.

My current code that is working with user creation and adding the user to Firebase db:

```
  const [signUpForm, setSignUpForm] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [createUserWithEmailAndPassword, user, loading, userError] =
    useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth);

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (error) setError("");
      if (signUpForm.password !== signUpForm.confirmPassword) {
        return setError("Password do not match");
      }
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signUpForm.email, signUpForm.password);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error.msg);
    }
  };

  //Sets inputs value in signUpForm useState
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setSignUpForm((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  //Adds the user to Firebase db
  const createUserDocument = async (User) => {
    await addDoc(
      collection(firestore, "Users"),
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(User))
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      createUserDocument(user.user);
      console.log(user);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections have no fields. Collections have documents. You have mistake in `updateDoc()` function.

Here is how you should update documents:

```js
await updateDoc(doc(firestore, "Users", user.uid), {
  isAdmin: false
});
```

In your arrow function, you have another mistake. You're creating a document with random ID. You should use `setDoc()` instead of `addDoc()` function.

```js
  const createUserDocument = async (user) => {
    await setDoc(
      doc(firestore, "Users", user.uid),
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(User))
    );
  };
```

***Edit:***

Assuming your `user` object is a `User` not `UserCredential` it has `.uid` field not `.id`. If it is a `UserCredential` you need first take a user so: `user.user.uid`

Comment: I get an error when I add user.id on them both. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Comment: @Mintee Edited I'm not sure, but your user might be a UserCredential object, not a User object. And User got ID in `.uid`. Learn to use CTRL + Space buttons. It shows you what you can use in objects.